# Receiving an "Exception Thrown" during loop

Tags: c++

The exception I have received was

```
Exception thrown at 0x70F8516F (vcruntime140d.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x723D9C18.
```

It occurs during the final iteration of user defined information into an array during a for loop:

```
int k;
cout << "Enter array size:";
cin >> k;
while (k > 3) {

    cout << "Array size too big, please reenter" << endl;
    cin >> k;

}

Player *ptr = new Player[k];

string n;
int s;

for (int i = 0; k >= i; i++) {

    cout << "Enter name" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    ptr[i].setName(n);

    cout << "Enter score" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    ptr[i].setScore(s);

    ptr[i].getName();
    ptr[i].getScore();

}
```

And it directs me to the end of my setName function

```
void Player::setName(string n) {

    name = n;

}
```

Comment: Buffer overrun.  What happens when `i == k` in the loop?

Comment: In loops if first iterating value is zero then end condition is usually `<` (or `>`), instead of `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: Just replace `k >= i` with `k > i` in the for loop. Classic way is to use `i < k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
Player *ptr = new Player[k+1];
```

Suppose your value of `k` is 5 then your loop will iterate 6 times (0 to 5) , and you have allocated space only for 5 objects. That's why it will throw an exception.

Comment: Why do you think `Player` needs to be declared with one more entry?  What if the loop condition is wrong?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but ... this will prevent exception too :) As well as for any other possitive N: `new Player [k+N]` ha-ha...

Comment: I looked at the code.  Your answer assumes that the OP wants one more entry, but there is no proof of that.  If what is required is 5 players, then the number of `Players` should be 5, not 6.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , Yeah , you are right, Actually I read your comment wrong. And replied hastily.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , His question was why he is getting an exception, that's what I have tried to explain. :)

Answer (score 1):

your array size should be (k+1) or the for loop should be like :

```
for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {

cout << "Enter name" << endl;
cin >> n;
ptr[i].setName(n);

cout << "Enter score" << endl;
cin >> s;
ptr[i].setScore(s);

ptr[i].getName();
ptr[i].getScore();

}
```